# Make Player Character Dash/Charge towards mouse cursor on click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a dash/charge attack towards the cursor position with a max dash length and I am unsure how to do it as I am very new to Unity and coding in general.

It would be similar to this code except instead of teleporting the character would dash.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, rayLength, layerMask) && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            {
                Vector3 hitPosition = new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, hit.point.z);
                player.transform.position = hitPosition;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

search youtube for "Different Ways to move an object in Unity".
the soultion i suggest is to use AddForce instead of Transform.Position.
Examples:

1. using AddForce is just like kicking a ball in a direction.
2. using transform.position is just like carrying the ball to the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `AddForce` could look something like this:

```
// Gets executed, on every left click
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    float force = 5f;
    Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    // Gets the position of your mouse cursor in world space
    Vector3 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    
    rb.AddForce(direction * force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

You would put this into the `Update` Method.

Note however, that you should probably cache `Camera.main` and the `Rigidbody2D`.
Doing the lookups every frame is very inefficient.

You could / should also make the `force` a field available in the inspector, so you can easily tweak it to your liking :)